# BeautifulSoup finding attributes of a table row

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I got the html below, I want to get the text of event_timestamp

```
<tr id="eventRowId_454169" event_attr_id="25" event_timestamp="2022-07-19 12:30:00" onclick="javascript:changeEventDisplay(454169, this, 'overview');">
                <td class="first left time">15:30</td>
                <td class="flagCur"> USD</td>                   <td class="sentiment" title="High Volatility Expected"><i class="newSiteIconsSprite grayFullBullishIcon middle"></i><i class="newSiteIconsSprite grayFullBullishIcon middle"></i><i class="newSiteIconsSprite grayFullBullishIcon middle"></i></td>                <td class="left event">Building Permits (Jun)</td>

                                                            </tr>
```

Below is my code

```
Time = row.tr['event_timestamp']
```

Am getting None , what can I change to get the time?

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<tr id="eventRowId_454169" event_attr_id="25" event_timestamp="2022-07-19 12:30:00" onclick="javascript:changeEventDisplay(454169, this, 'overview');">
                <td class="first left time">15:30</td>
                <td class="flagCur"> USD</td>                   <td class="sentiment" title="High Volatility Expected"><i class="newSiteIconsSprite grayFullBullishIcon middle"></i><i class="newSiteIconsSprite grayFullBullishIcon middle"></i><i class="newSiteIconsSprite grayFullBullishIcon middle"></i></td>                <td class="left event">Building Permits (Jun)</td>

                                                            </tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
time = soup.select_one('tr').get('event_timestamp')
print(time)
```